# How to get the a file from drag n dropped paths

Tags: java, linux, file, path, filenotfoundexception

So really noobie question i suppose but i made a JTextField where the user can drag and drop files in to avoid clicking through the swing tree for half an hour. This gives me a String like
`file:///media/raphael/Coding/Test/Test%20rscs/Test%20Exercise.asf` (i know the file format is unnusual, its generated from my own code) This path doesn't work because of the %20 and the file:// at the beginning. So i made a function giving me this: `/media/raphael/Coding/Test/Test rscs/Test Exercise.asf` But this still doesnt work when plugged into `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.path));`, giving me a File not found exception. The strange thing is that when i get the exception in intellij, the path is displayed as a link which leads to the file, so the path is actually valid? What do i have to do in order to make java recognize the path?

Comment: Maybe BufferedReader is looking for a relative path, but you're supplying a global path?

Comment: What can i use instead of it then? (I actually didn't know that because i had relative paths for Windows apps which i later exchanged with global paths, but this worked for some reason then, maybe the OS difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that drag 'n' drop adds an aditional space at the end of anything dropped. This space of course is not visible in error messages or `System.out.println();`. Therefore the solution is to remove the last char of the String if it is ' '.